# Devise (or OmniAuth) appending "#_" to URL after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, omniauth

I'm using Devise and OmniAuth (Facebook) in a Rails 3 app.  I just started noticing this behavior recently.

When a user signs in, he is redirected to his dashboard, however, the characters "#_" are being appended to the url.  The only thing I can think of now is a conflict between the routes created by:

```
  resources :users
```

and

```
  # User Authentication
  devise_for :users,
         :singular => :user,
         :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'} do
    get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Comment: Seeing same with #_=_ in my Rails 3.1 app on some urls. Not using devise, but Omniauth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this only happening with Facebook? If so it is probably related to: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/. Notice how Facebook outlines that they changed the session redirect handling to append a `#_=_` to responses. I'm not sure why this was done, however you may be able to fix it by  supplying an explicit redirect url.